# @Valid is not triggering - Spring MVC 3.2

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

For some reason, its not working. I searched and tried all the solutions found on the net. No dice. Looks like I am missing something.

My Beam:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employees")
public class Person {

    private Integer person_id;
    private String name;
    private String name2;
    private String email;
    private double phone;
    private String desc;

    @Id
    @Max(value=500)
    @Column (name="id")
    public Integer getPerson_id() {
        return person_id;
    }

    public void setPerson_id(Integer person_id) {
        this.person_id = person_id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column (name="fn")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name="ln")
    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }
    public void setName2(String name2) {
        this.name2 = name2;
    }

    @Email
    @Column (name="em", unique = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Column(name="phone")
    public double getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }
    public void setPhone(double phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column (name="de")
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getPerson_id() + " - " + getName() + " - " + getName2() + " - " +  getEmail();
    }
}
```

Controller Method That handles POST:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/register", method =  RequestMethod.POST, headers="Accept=*/*")
public String registerUer( @javax.validation.Valid Person registerForm, BindingResult br){


    System.out.println( "Erros?" + br.hasErrors());
    if ( br.hasErrors() ) {
        System.out.println(br.getAllErrors());
    }
    System.out.println(registerForm);
    return "thankyou";
}
```

home.jsp

```
 <form:form action="register.htm" commandName="registerForm" method="post">
  Name1: <form:input path="name"/><br />
  Name2: <form:input path="name2"/><br />
  Email: <form:input path="email"/><br />
  Desc:  <form:input path="desc" /><br />
  Phone: <form:input path="phone" /><br />
  <input type="submit" />
 </form:form>
```

application context xml file:

```
  <mvc:annotation-driven />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvcsample"/>
  <context:annotation-config/>
  <import resource="hibernate_config.xml"/>

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <property name="prefix">
  <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
   </property>
   <property name="suffix">
  <value>.jsp</value>
   </property>
  </bean>

  <bean id="contentNegotiationManager"    
        class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
        <!-- Turn off working out content type based on URL file extension, should fall back   
                to looking at the Accept headers -->
   <property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
  </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="messages" />
  </bean>
```

I always get `hasErrors()` return false
I have hibernate validator (GA jar) file in my classspath. And I see this loaded:

```
  INFO  [Version] Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you try with validation annotations on setters?

Comment: Will try that anyways. But is there a difference using on fields vs setters?

Comment: You have annotations on your getters..

Comment: I forgot to realize, I already have the annotations on `setters`. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected if I remove JPA annotations (as I wanted to avoid further configuration for db) and use your form and controller code.

Definitely there is some missing piece, can you try by making a simple pojo with validation annotations and see.

Comment: There is no database stuff involved at all  in my POJO. Do you want me to remove `@Column` annotation?

Comment: I commented out the JPA annotations. But still no dice! I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Did you try this and it worked for you? Maybe I am missing some jars? (Not using Maven). But I guess if I am missing something, it should pop out in the log/when I submit.

Comment: Yes I tried your code and it worked fine. You may check out https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase project. I have it all the time as a side project so that I can experiment with different features.

Comment: Can you let me know how to use your sample app? is there a brief write up on how to setup and use it? Any DB necessary?

Comment: This app is spring-mvc showcase i.e. a demo of spring-mvc features provided by spring people see this blog http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/. How to setup and run is explained in https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/README.md page. Basically you need git client, maven and active internet. you may download the src in zipped format at https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/archive/master.zip. There is no db required and will teach a lot about using spring-mvc.