# @Valid annotation - This annotation disallowed for this location

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, bean-validation

I have controller method that has `@Valid` annotation to enforce JSR303 Bean validation.

But when I just give `@Valid` is shows"

```
This annotation @Valid is disallowed for this location
```

I can get rid of this by giving full package path `@javax.validation.Valid`. It does not show the above message if I use this.

My question is, would there be any conflict that is forcing me to give full package name?
Or some jars missing?

I wouldn't be asking this question, if `@Valid` validation is working fine. But its not working either, though there is no compile or run time error. It is just not triggering.

I posted this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270946/valid-is-not-triggering-spring-mvc-3-2?noredirect=1#comment23303599_16270946%20%5B@valid%20not%20working%5D) in a different thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your imports. I guess you are not importing `javax.validation.Valid` when you just use `@Valid`.

Comment: Hmm.. It may sound dumb on my part You are right. BUT, I never wrote import statement by hand. When there is an error, I hover the mouse over it and eclipse shows the required import and boom, I am done. But this one looked like a special case.

Comment: @KevinRave I, of course, assumed that it was an auto import :) Have you by any chance checked the imports of your POJO from the other post as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import below packages for `@Valid` and `@Size` to work:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
```

And the necessary jars which are required to work this are given below:

- classmate-1.0.0.jar
- hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
- javax.el-2.2.4.jar
- javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
- jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.ja

You can download above jars from http://hibernate.org/validator/

Comment: hibernate-validator file contains inside dist folder and others inside dist>lib>required

Answer (score 0):

Use the annotation above any method where you want to use the fetched String(Remember the properties file fetch only in string datatype)